# Using the Google+ API with xCode/iOS (ARC)

Tags: ios, xcode, api

I want access to my Google+-Timeline for an iOS-App.

Following the Google-Documentation I imported the libGTlTouchStaticLib.a and library's header files.

After trying to build the project the following warning/error occured:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file ..../libGTLTouchStaticLib.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
```

How do I build the Lib for xCode 4.3.2 architecture?

Comment: what does the command: file libGTLTouchStaticLib.a  return? It sounds like it's compiled for ARM (the device) and you are running it in the simulator (i386).  YOu might also want to try it on a device.

Comment: Yes, u were right. I fixed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what does the command: file libGTLTouchStaticLib.a return? It sounds like it's compiled for ARM (the device) and you are running it in the simulator (i386). YOu might also want to try it on a device.